# How to add group in tomcat-users.xml?

Tags: tomcat

How to add group in tomcat-users.xml and is there many versions of this file. In some file there is only  and in some there is

Comment: by 'group' do you mean 'role'? and what does the last sentence mean?

Comment: By group, I meant the group of users or roles whichever is possible

Comment: This question looks incomplete, can you complete it ?

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat has only users and roles: all permissions are given based upon "role" which I suppose could mean "group".

In order to add a role to `tomcat-users.xml`, all you need to do is type it in. Here is the stock `tomcat-users.xml` file that ships with Tomcat (7.0.29):

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
</tomcat-users>
```

Note that everything is surrounded with XML comments, so it's effectively empty.

Let's say that you want to add the role "myGroup" and put yourself ("kad") into it:

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
  <role rolename="myGroup" />
  <user username="kad" password="secret" roles="myGroup" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Now you just need to configure your webapp to check for the "myGroup" role when allowing access to various resources. You can do this within your webapp's `web.xml` file, or programatically using the `ServletRequest.isUserInRole("myGroup")` method.

Note that you shouldn't really use `tomcat-users.xml` for authentication in a production environment except for maybe using Tomcat's 'manager' webapp: it's just too in-flexible for anything industrial-strength.